# Routing & Navigation example app not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the sample from the Angular 2 [ROUTING & NAVIGATION docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) to work.
It runs fine on [the example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/), but if you download the code and use the app directly in a [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) project, it fails to run.
The 'Loading...' message never goes away and there are no errors in the console at first.  After a while, these errors in show up:

`service-worker.js:1 A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

The app provides a good example, and since it has all this great documentation, I would like to use it as a starting point for further work.

The example Tour of Heroes app has various seemingly disconnected manifestations.
This version seems the most mature and complete.  It would be nice to be able to run it locally.

You can reproduce the errors by cloning the quickstart, and downloading the plunker and replacing the app folder from quickstart with the one from the plunker.
You would also need to run npm install before doing npm start.
I also changed main.js to app.module.js in the systemjs.config.js file like this:

```
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './app.module.js',
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I took the advice of @andrew554 and added  in the index, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set base, which was mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href):

> LIVE EXAMPLE NOTE
>
> We have to get tricky when we run the live example because the host
>   service sets the application base address dynamically. That's why we
>   replace the  with a script that writes a  tag on
>   the fly to match.
>
> `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`
>
> We should only need this trick for the live example,
>   not production code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Set the base href -->
         <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

just replace `<script> ...` with `<base href="/">`

Comment: Hi @andrew554, thanks for the reply.  I tried the base href solution but there are no errors and a blank screen (just the “Loading …” string)  I created [this repo](https://github.com/timofeysie/router-quickstart) to demonstrate the problem.